# Confused on topology of function spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am beginning to study functional analysis, and have been introduced to the topologies such as the topology of pointwise convergence, the topology of uniform convergence, and the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

I see results such as

> If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space then set of continuous functions mapping $X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathbb{C}^X$ in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

I am a bit unclear on what this is saying exactly. From what I understand, the open sets in this topology are functions $g$ such that
$$\big\{g \in \mathbb{C}^X : \sup_{x \in K} |g(x) - f(x)| < n^{-1}\big\} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}, f \in \mathbb{C}^X, K \subset X \text { compact}.$$

In other words, for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f \in \mathbb{C}^X$, and some compact set $K \subset X$, the function $g$ in the above set is an open set. Considering all functions/open sets $g$ that are obtained from various $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f \in \mathbb{C}^X$, and compact sets $K \subset X$, we have our space. Is this correct?

Assuming the answer is yes, suppose we have a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ converging to a function $g$. The theorem is then saying that if each $g_n$ is is in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets and is also continuous, then $g$ must also be in this topology and continuous as well. Hence the set of continuous functions is closed in this topology. Is this correct?

I suspect what is causing me some trouble is I've always thought about function spaces being closed or complete in regards to some metric, and have not yet seen topologies defined in terms of functions, so this sort of object is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not of a topology. The sets that you have described are a *basis* of the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

And asserting that the set of continuous functions is closed with respect to that topology means that every convergent sequence of continuous functions converges to a continuous function, if that topology is first-countable. I don't know whether it is or not.

Asserting that the set of continuous functions is closed with respect to that topology means that the set of discontinuous functions is open. And that means that, is $f\colon X\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is discontinuous, then there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ and a natural number $n$ such that, if $g\colon X\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is such that$$\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)-g(x)|<\frac1n,$$then $g$ is discontinuous too.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to visualize what the open sets look like. Given that the sets in my post form a basis, does that mean the open sets consist of unions of these functions? How should one visualize that?

Comment: The answers are “yes” and “I don't know” respectively.

Comment: Thanks, that really clears things. The only part I am still confused on is the second part of your post. If we wish to show that the set of continuous functions is closed, since we do not know if the space if first countable, we instead show that the space of discontinuous functions is open? I must be overlooking something, but are the two approaches not equivalent? The text I am using proves this by considering a closed set $E \subset \mathbb{C}$ and proves that $f^{-1}(E)$ must also be closed for some $f$ in the closure of the set of continuous functions.

Comment: How is this approach from the text sufficient if we are not assuming anything about first countability? Or is it always implicitly implied that we are speaking of convergence in terms of nets? Edit: I believe this may be because the $\mathbb{C}$ is a metric space.

Comment: Yes, proving that the set of continuous functions is closed is equivalent to proving that the set of discontinuous functions is open. I made a mistake in my comment about that topology being metrizable, and I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help!